# Can I create a list view made up of multiple related object fields (api/ lwc /etc.)?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, appexchange, list-view, custom

I'm trying to create a list view composed of a custom object, the activity/task object, and their fields.  I'd like to use list views for the mass update functionality (although I'm open to other suggestions).

I know this isn't possible out of the box.  It looks like there's an appexchange offering that has this functionality so that's leading me to believe it's possible somehow.  I've gone down LWC, apex, and appexchange rabbit holes looking for a solution, but before I keep looking I'm hoping that someone will at least be able to tell me if it's even possible.

1. Can I create a LWC for this use case and put that on a Lightning App page?  If so, am I limited to fields of only 1 object within the data table?
2. It looks like I can create a list view using apex; if so, same question: am I limited to fields of only 1 object within the data table?
3. If neither of these are possible options, can someone point me to another option that might be feasible?

I'm willing to figure this out on my own, I just need somebody to point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Yes, although you're not really creating the list view in apex.  All you're doing is getting a dataset from Apex.  The list view functionality would be done via lwc. 3. see 1 and 2.  However, based on your line of questioning, it doesn't seem like you are proficient in lwc (I could be wrong).  This will take a long time if you've never done one before.  I'd hire a consultant to do it if that's what you really need.

Comment: Hey @willard, thanks for the reply.  You are correct that I don't have too much experience with LWCs, but this is only a pet project for me to play around with for learning.  I have experience with java and some js, and I can usually pick things up pretty quickly. So just to clarify when you answer 'yes', are you saying that 'yes, this is possible', or 'yes, I am limited to fields of 1 object'?  Thanks again

Comment: yes - this is possible